# Does WhatsApp keep my status when I change phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am also changing my phone, maintaining my same number. Will my status be restored to "Hi there using whatsapp"?. i.e., the default?

Comment: No, the account informations (including status) associated with your phone number are transferred to the new phone.

Answer (score -1):

No. The status is stored on WhatsApp's servers along with other basic information about your account, such as phone no, profile picture, last seen and changing your device **doesn't** automatically change them.